# ASP.NET redirect page in gridview selectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, gridview

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I redirect from another page using selectedindexchanged

My html code looks like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridsummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True"
                HorizontalAlign="Left" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridsummary_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="sstat" HeaderText="STATUS">
                   <ItemStyle Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="ctr" HeaderText="COUNT" >
                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="150px" />
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
               <HeaderStyle CssClass="GRIDVIEW_TITLE" />
               <RowStyle CssClass="GRIDVIEW_DETAILS" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

And i have a code in my OnSelectedIndexChanged like this

```
protected void gridsummary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gridsummary.SelectedRow;
        string sStat = row.Cells[0].Text;


    }
```

What i want is `if sStat='Delivered'` it will be redirected to this page `webViewDelivered.aspx` and `if sStat='For Processing'` it will be redirected to another page. Is there a way to do that in SelectedIndexChanged? Or can i add an attribute on selectedindexchanged so that i can have like `<a href='webViewDelivered.aspx'/>`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Response.Redirect` to redirect  to the page you desired.[Here is more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
   protected void gridsummary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    GridViewRow row = gridsummary.SelectedRow;
    if(row.Cells[0].Text.Equals("Delivered"))
    {
           Response.Redirect("\webViewDelivered.aspx");
    }
    else if(row.Cells[0].Text.Equals("For Processing"))
    {
           Response.Redirect("\Anathoryourpage.aspx");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much I've tried many codes on this, i even tried OnRowDatabound. LOL. Big thanks to you!